# LaTeX Error: Illegal parameter number in pgfplots coordinate list

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, errors, compiling, coordinates

I am experiencing a persistent error when trying to compile a pgfplots scatter plot in LaTeX. The error message I receive is:

> ./test.tex:23: Illegal parameter number in definition of \pgfmaththisrow@.
>
> 1
> l.23 };

This error occurs at the end of my data series in the plot, directly after the closing bracket of the coordinates. Here is a minimal working example (MWE) that replicates the issue:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={n vs. Number of zeros in coloring solution},
    xlabel={Number of zeros},
    ylabel={$n$ (Number of unknowns in the LP problem)},
    xmin=18, xmax=30,
    ymin=6000, ymax=15000,
    xtick={19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29},
    ytick={7000,8000,9000,10000,11000,12000,13000,14000}
]
\addplot[
  only marks,
  mark=x, 
  mark options={scale=1.5, draw=blue}
] coordinates {
  (19, 14941)
  (20, 13901)
  (20, 13953)
  (20, 13979)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I have only included a few data points, my actual plot requires a large number of points. I am using macOS Monterey (ver 12.6.5).

Here is the entire log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.4.7)  20 MAR 2024 17:11
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**Zeros_Versus_n.tex
(./Zeros_Versus_n.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-03-06>
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cls
Document Class: standalone 2018/03/26 v1.3a Class to compile TeX sub-files stan
dalone
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/shellesc.sty
Package: shellesc 2019/11/08 v1.0c unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
Package shellesc Info: Restricted shell escape enabled on input line 77.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks15
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks16

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count167
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
\sa@internal=\count168
\c@sapage=\count169

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cfg
File: standalone.cfg 2018/03/26 v1.3a Default configuration file for 'standalon
e' class
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count170
\c@section=\count171
\c@subsection=\count172
\c@subsubsection=\count173
\c@paragraph=\count174
\c@subparagraph=\count175
\c@figure=\count176
\c@table=\count177
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen134
)
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/latex/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/latex/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/latex/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/utilities/pgfutil-comm
on.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks17
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen135
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen136

(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/utilities/pgfutil-comm
on-lists.tex))
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/utilities/pgfutil-late
x.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box45
 (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty
Package: everyshi 2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
))
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/utilities/pgfrcs.code.
tex
Package: pgfrcs 2013/12/20 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.28)
))
Package: pgf 2013/12/18 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.14)

(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/latex/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2019/11/30 v1.2a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2019/11/30 v1.4a Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 105.

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen137
\Gin@req@width=\dimen138
)
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/latex/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/systemlayer/pgfsys.cod
e.tex
Package: pgfsys 2013/11/30 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.47)

(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/utilities/pgfkeys.code
.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks18
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks19

(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/utilities/pgfkeysfilte
red.code.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks20
))
\pgf@x=\dimen139
\pgf@y=\dimen140
\pgf@xa=\dimen141
\pgf@ya=\dimen142
\pgf@xb=\dimen143
\pgf@yb=\dimen144
\pgf@xc=\dimen145
\pgf@yc=\dimen146
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read2
\c@pgf@counta=\count178
\c@pgf@countb=\count179
\c@pgf@countc=\count180
\c@pgf@countd=\count181
\t@pgf@toka=\toks21
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks22
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks23

(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/systemlayer/pgf.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2008/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-pdftex.def

(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdf
tex.def
File: pgfsys-pdftex.def 2013/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.33)

(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/systemlayer/pgfsys-com
mon-pdf.def
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2013/10/10  (rcs-revision 1.13)
)))
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/systemlayer/pgfsyssoft
path.code.tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count182
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count183
)
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/systemlayer/pgfsysprot
ocol.code.tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
)) (/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2004/07/04 v2.00 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 136.
Package xcolor Info: Color model `cmy' added on input line 972.
Package xcolor Info: Color model `hsb' added on input line 980.
Package xcolor Info: Color model `HTML' added on input line 1000.
Package xcolor Info: Color model `HSB' added on input line 1006.
Package xcolor Info: Color model `Gray' added on input line 1012.
)
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/basiclayer/pgfcore.cod
e.tex
Package: pgfcore 2010/04/11 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)

(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/math/pgfmathcalc.code.
tex
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/math/pgfmathutil.code.
tex)
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/math/pgfmathparser.cod
e.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen147
\pgfmath@count=\count184
\pgfmath@box=\box46
\pgfmath@toks=\toks24
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks25
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks26
)
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/math/pgfmathfunctions.
code.tex
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/math/pgfmathfunctions.
basic.code.tex)
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/math/pgfmathfunctions.
trigonometric.code.tex)
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/math/pgfmathfunctions.
random.code.tex)
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/math/pgfmathfunctions.
comparison.code.tex)
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/math/pgfmathfunctions.
base.code.tex)
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/math/pgfmathfunctions.
round.code.tex)
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/math/pgfmathfunctions.
misc.code.tex)
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/math/pgfmathfunctions.
integerarithmetics.code.tex)))
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/math/pgfmathfloat.code
.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count185
))
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/basiclayer/pgfcorepoin
ts.code.tex
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2013/10/07  (rcs-revision 1.27)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen148
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen149
\pgf@picminy=\dimen150
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen151
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen152
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen153
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen154
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen155
\pgf@xx=\dimen156
\pgf@xy=\dimen157
\pgf@yx=\dimen158
\pgf@yy=\dimen159
\pgf@zx=\dimen160
\pgf@zy=\dimen161
)
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/basiclayer/pgfcorepath
construct.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2013/10/07  (rcs-revision 1.29)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen162
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen163
)
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/basiclayer/pgfcorepath
usage.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2013/12/13  (rcs-revision 1.23)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen164
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen165
)
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/basiclayer/pgfcorescop
es.code.tex
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2013/10/09  (rcs-revision 1.44)
\pgfpic=\box47
\pgf@hbox=\box48
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box49
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count186
)
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/basiclayer/pgfcoregrap
hicstate.code.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2013/09/19  (rcs-revision 1.11)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen166
)
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/basiclayer/pgfcoretran
sformations.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2013/10/10  (rcs-revision 1.17)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen167
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen168
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen169
)
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/basiclayer/pgfcorequic
k.code.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2008/10/09  (rcs-revision 1.3)
)
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/basiclayer/pgfcoreobje
cts.code.tex
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2006/10/11  (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/basiclayer/pgfcorepath
processing.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
)
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/basiclayer/pgfcorearro
ws.code.tex
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2013/11/07  (rcs-revision 1.40)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen170
)
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/basiclayer/pgfcoreshad
e.code.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.15)
\pgf@max=\dimen171
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count187
)
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/basiclayer/pgfcoreimag
e.code.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.18)

(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/basiclayer/pgfcoreexte
rnal.code.tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box50
))
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/basiclayer/pgfcorelaye
rs.code.tex
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2013/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/basiclayer/pgfcoretran
sparency.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2013/09/30  (rcs-revision 1.5)
)
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/basiclayer/pgfcorepatt
erns.code.tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2013/11/07  (rcs-revision 1.5)
)))
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/modules/pgfmoduleshape
s.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2013/10/31  (rcs-revision 1.34)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box51
)
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/modules/pgfmoduleplot.
code.tex
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2013/07/31  (rcs-revision 1.12)
)
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/latex/compatibility/pgfcomp-ve
rsion-0-65.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2007/07/03 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen172
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen173
)
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/latex/compatibility/pgfcomp-ve
rsion-1-18.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2007/07/23 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.1)
))
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/latex/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/latex/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/utilities/pgfkeys.code
.tex)) (/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/latex/math/pgfmath.sty
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/math/pgfmath.code.tex)
)
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/utilities/pgffor.code.
tex
Package: pgffor 2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.25)

(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/math/pgfmath.code.tex)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen174
\pgffor@skip=\dimen175
\pgffor@stack=\toks27
\pgffor@toks=\toks28
))
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/frontendlayer/tikz.cod
e.tex
Package: tikz 2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.142)

(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/libraries/pgflibrarypl
othandlers.code.tex
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2013/08/31 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count188
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen176
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen177
\tikz@lasty=\dimen178
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen179
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen180
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen181
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen182
\tikz@figbox=\box52
\tikz@figbox@bg=\box53
\tikz@tempbox=\box54
\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box55
\tikztreelevel=\count189
\tikznumberofchildren=\count190
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count191
\tikz@fig@count=\count192

(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/modules/pgfmodulematri
x.code.tex
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2013/09/17  (rcs-revision 1.8)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count193
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count194
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count195
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count196

(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/frontendlayer/librarie
s/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2008/06/17 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.2)
)))
\sa@box=\box56
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.revision.tex)
Package: pgfplots 2020/02/29 v1.17 Data Visualization (1.17)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotscore.code.tex
\t@pgfplots@toka=\toks29
\t@pgfplots@tokb=\toks30
\t@pgfplots@tokc=\toks31
\pgfplots@tmpa=\dimen183
\c@pgfplots@coordindex=\count197
\c@pgfplots@scanlineindex=\count198

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/sys/pgfplotssysgeneric
.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/pgfplotslibrary.c
ode.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplot
soldpgfsupp_loader.code.tex
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/libraries/pgflibraryfp
u.code.tex)
Package pgfplots: loading complementary arithmetics for your pgf version...

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplot
soldpgfsupp_pgflibraryfpu.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplot
soldpgfsupp_pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count199
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplot
soldpgfsupp_trig_format.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplot
soldpgfsupp_leq.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsutil.code
.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplots
liststructure.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplots
liststructureext.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplots
array.code.tex
\c@pgfplotsarray@tmp=\count266
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplots
matrix.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/numtable/pgfplotstable
shared.code.tex
\c@pgfplotstable@counta=\count267
\t@pgfplotstable@a=\toks32
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplots
deque.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsbinary.co
de.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsbinary.da
ta.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsutil.verb
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/pgflibrarypgfplot
s.surfshading.code.tex
\c@pgfplotslibrarysurf@no=\count268

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/sys/pgflibrarypgfplots
.surfshading.pgfsys-pdftex.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotscolormap.
code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotscolor.cod
e.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsstackedplots.c
ode.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsplothandlers.c
ode.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsmeshplothandle
r.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsmeshplotimage.
code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.scaling.code.
tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotscoordprocessin
g.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.errorbars.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.markers.code.
tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsticks.code.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.paths.code.te
x)
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/frontendlayer/librarie
s/tikzlibrarydecorations.code.tex
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/modules/pgfmoduledecor
ations.code.tex
\pgfdecoratedcompleteddistance=\dimen184
\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance=\dimen185
\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentcompleteddistance=\dimen186
\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance=\dimen187
\pgf@decorate@distancetomove=\dimen188
\pgf@decorate@repeatstate=\count269
\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude=\dimen189
\pgfdecorationsegmentlength=\dimen190
)
\tikz@lib@dec@box=\box57
)
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/frontendlayer/librarie
s/tikzlibrarydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/libraries/decorations/
pgflibrarydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex))
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/frontendlayer/librarie
s/tikzlibrarydecorations.pathreplacing.code.tex
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/libraries/decorations/
pgflibrarydecorations.pathreplacing.code.tex))
\pgfplots@numplots=\count270
\pgfplots@xmin@reg=\dimen191
\pgfplots@xmax@reg=\dimen192
\pgfplots@ymin@reg=\dimen193
\pgfplots@ymax@reg=\dimen194
\pgfplots@zmin@reg=\dimen195
\pgfplots@zmax@reg=\dimen196
)
(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/frontendlayer/librarie
s/tikzlibraryplotmarks.code.tex
File: tikzlibraryplotmarks.code.tex 2008/01/09 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.1)

(/Users/mgarvie/Library/texmf/tex/latex/base/tex/generic/libraries/pgflibrarypl
otmarks.code.tex
File: pgflibraryplotmarks.code.tex 2013/07/20 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.13)
)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def
File: l3backend-pdfmode.def 2020-03-12 L3 backend support: PDF mode
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count271
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box58
)
(./Zeros_Versus_n.aux)
\openout1 = `Zeros_Versus_n.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
 ABD: EveryShipout initializing macro
```

Comment: The version of TeXShop is probably irrelevant. The versions of the packages you use are more relevant. I cannot reproduce the error with an up-to-date TeX installation. Can you show the first lines of your log and maybe also the version of PGF?

Comment: I'm using PGF 3.00. Here is the first few lines of the log file:

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.4.7)  20 MAR 2024 16:15
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**Zeros_Versus_n.tex
(./Zeros_Versus_n.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-03-06>
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cls
Document Class: standalone 2018/03/26 v1.3a Class to compile TeX sub-files stan
dalone

Comment: your example gives no error in a current system, you are using an older distribution (texlive 2024 is released but you have texlive 2020) but you could show your full log in a code block in the question (you can't format code in comments)

Comment: I checked on overleaf and your example gives no error in any texlive since 2019

Comment: I have now attached the entire log file in the question as a code block.

Comment: The log file that you attached does not contain errors. It also doesn't seem to be complete - maybe it got cut off because of the character limits of a StackExchange post? If that is the case try to delete a bit from the middle of the log file, the start and the end of the log is the most important.

Comment: Hm, in any case, PGF 3.0.0 is really dated: 2013, that's eleven years.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure now that the issue is that PGF needs updating. But I've tried updating this package and failed. It seems to me you have to be a computer expert to do this! If anyone knows of a script that puts everything where it belongs automatically I would appreciate it. In my current Mac system the PGF folder is at Library/texmf/tex/latex/base. I downloaded from CTAN the updated 'base' package, replaced it, but this just gave other errors.

Comment: I'll just re-install the whole Latex bundle.

Comment: If your PGF is that old, just update your installation of TeX e.g. MacTeX or whatever. PGF should not be in the directory you say it is. `texmf/tex/latex/base/` is for core LaTeX - not contributed packages.